# ViewFlipper not working along with navigation drawer

Tags: java, c#, android, eclipse, xamarin

I am trying to integrate a navigation drawer and ViewFlipper in my application , but they don’t seem to work together, some part of code is below :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/trip_detail_bot_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:minHeight="52dp"
    android:background="#51A31B"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/first_viewflipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_swipe_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:minHeight="52dp"
            android:background="#51A31B"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#FFFEFF"
                android:id="@+id/trip_detail_bot_text"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="SWIPE to start the trip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pickuptime_image"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/swipe_right_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

When i removed "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" and using ViewFlipper inside "LinearLayout", its working..

Please help me if anybody have solution of it.....

Comment: Is anyone here who can solve this error....i need it urgently..please help me as such as possible !!

Comment: no one here to help ??